# How can I respond a list of elements in application/xml with Spring?

Tags: xml, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-web

I'm an immigrant from JAX-RS to Spring.

With my following code,

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<Item>> read() {
    final List<Item> body
            = range(0, current().nextInt(1, 10))
            .mapToObj(i -> Item.newRandomInstance())
            .collect(toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(body);
}
```

I get `200` for `application/json` but `406` for `application/xml`.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Is there any functionality for automatic plural wrapping?

Here comes my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        //    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    //  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path') // for gs-rest-service
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- springfox-swagger
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0'
    //compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp') // rabbitmq
}
```

Comment: Do you have both json and xml message converter? are you sending requests with different Accept header (application/xml, application/json)?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich Yes, I'm testing using curl.

Comment: I'm also using `spring-boot-starter-web`. I've checked that it configures no `HttpMessageConverter`'s by default. So it seems like you have json converter while forgot to configure for xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting my own answer for others.

I added following dependency.

```
// for application/xml 
// remove if you don't need to deal with XML.
runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.1'
```